# when width size change the header div what is the better solution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have a question to ask which is

What is the best way to change my header content when the width size change?

[image]

can it be done with php session = true? Like when the width less or equal 500px it will auto change the whole header? or it must done with javascript or jquery would be better?

Comment: Why you tag `PHP`?

Comment: i was thinking about can it be done with php function? like i create one more header for the width change the header will switch to other header.

Comment: but maybe it is related with html css so i was remoeved it

Comment: The question that you have asked is basically related to responsive design. for that you have to use CSS media query. learn media query you will automatically got idea about how to do so

Comment: thx for your advice media query sloved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use media rules, it's the better solution for your case .

The @media rule is used to define different style rules for different media types/devices.

In CSS2 this was called media types, while in CSS3 it is called media queries.
Media queries look at the capability of the device, and can be used to check many things, such as:

- width and height of the viewport
- width and height of the device
- orientation (is the tablet/phone in landscape or portrait mode?)
- resolution
- and much more

for example if we are using one like this :

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }
}
```

it will give this background color to the body while the width is bigger than 480px.

You can also see this example which contain a menu that work fine on different widths using media queries : https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/o89pn61t/

Comment: tq!!! your answer really help me alot and thx for your example thats really helpful this is what i want.

Comment: since this is an old question that i ask before but i will ask a question. Does i can achieve this without using media query?

Comment: You can do it as a mobile version, but you will need to make a different layouts one for desktop and one for mobiles then you will load the layout depending on the device  http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/redirects/mobile-redirect

Comment: so media query is still the best way to do the mobile layout? i saw on a website which i may need to include each of the device width and height?[i found on google this is what i need to include on my css?](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)Or i just create 3 golbal version 1 for desktop, 1 for tablets and 1 for mobile?

Comment: you can create 3 global version 1 for desktop , 1 for tablets and 1 for mobile. you will not need to include each of the device width and height